# Libraries for Siamese networks

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

Which libraries/implementations for Siamese networks do exist?  I am most interested about R, C, and C++ implementations.

Comment: Questions asking for software, libraries, or code are off topic here.

Comment: @gung - no. There is no sentence "Questions asking for software, libraries, or code are off topic here" in http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic . If my question is off-topic, why http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41771/r-libraries-for-deep-learning is on-topic?

Comment: CV is a site for questions about *statistics* (ML, etc.). Asking for libraries is not a question about NNs, but a question about R implementations, which is not the same thing. You are right that the linked Q should be closed as well; that was posted when the sites policies were looser & not as clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) is written in C++ and allows you to implement a Siamese network:

http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/siamese.html

For R deep learning packages see this question:

[R libraries for deep learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41771/r-libraries-for-deep-learning)

They probably allow you to do what you want to do.